# Android Scrollview in a RelativeLayout Shows Blank

Tags: android, scrollview

i'm trying to make that all the content i have in a view can be scroll-able and what i'm doing is adding a Scrollview to the entire relative layout but when i do this anything is shown in the view. Below is the layout code i have with the Scrollview.

```
<Scrollview
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scroller"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fillViewport="true">
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="3dip">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/peliculaPortada"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detPeliculaTitulo"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/peliculaPortada"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/peliculaPortada"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="9pt" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detPeliculaRestriccion"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/peliculaPortada"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:text="Restricción: "
        android:layout_below="@id/detPeliculaTitulo"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="6pt" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detPeliculaGenero"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/peliculaPortada"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:text="Genero: "
        android:layout_below="@+id/detPeliculaRestriccion"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="6pt" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detPeliculaDuracion"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/peliculaPortada"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:text="Duración: "
        android:layout_below="@+id/detPeliculaGenero"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="6pt" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detPeliculaFechaEstreno"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/peliculaPortada"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:text="Fecha Estreno: "
        android:layout_below="@+id/detPeliculaDuracion"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="6pt" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sitioOficial"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/button_sitio_oficial"
        android:layout_below="@+id/peliculaPortada"
        android:text="Sitio Oficial"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/peliculaPortada"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/peliculaPortada"
        android:paddingTop="0pt" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/imdb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/button_link"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sitioOficial"
        android:text="Imdb"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/peliculaPortada"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/peliculaPortada" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/trailer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/button_trailer"
        android:layout_below="@id/imdb"
        android:text="Trailer"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/peliculaPortada"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/peliculaPortada"
        android:paddingTop="0pt" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sinopsis"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/button_sinopsis"
        android:layout_below="@id/trailer"
        android:text="Sinopsis"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/peliculaPortada"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/peliculaPortada"
        android:paddingTop="0pt" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detPeliculaPresentandose"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/sinopsis"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/peliculaPortada"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Presentandose En"
        android:paddingTop="2pt"
        android:textSize="7pt" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/detPeliculaTandas"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/detPeliculaPresentandose"
        android:paddingTop="3pt">
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found a solution through the use of an unusual method that was provided by doughw. The solution is to hack the listview to load to a full height.

Here is the link to the answer:
[How can I put a ListView into a ScrollView without it collapsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495890/how-can-i-put-a-listview-into-a-scrollview-without-it-collapsing/3495908#3495908)

Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue close to what you had and my problem was using layout_width="match_parent" on items that were aligned to the left or right of another item. I changed it to layout_width="wrap_content" and everything worked perfectly after that.

Answer (score -1):

Change the `wrap_content` to `fill_parent` in the scrollview height attribute.

Comment: fill_parent is obsoleted, it was renamed to `match_parent` in API level 8

Comment: Ah, okey. Did not know that:)